# Distribution of prime elements in algebraic number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be an algebraic (not necessarily Galois) number field.
Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$ and let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a nonzero ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Is the following statement correct?

Every class of $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{a})^\times$ contains a prime element.

If it is correct, is it known whether every class contains infinitely many prime elements?

I know that this is closely related to Chebotarev's density theorem, but I couldn't find anything related to this particular problem.

Comment: The standard procedure is using a search engine of your choice. With a little bit of experience you might come across https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29190/dirichlets-theorem-for-number-fields .